# Django admin missing Add / Edit buttons when using get_form()

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

When overriding the `get_form()` method in a ModelAdmin class, the "Add" and "Edit" (plus sign and pencil) icons do not appear next to any field on the admin page, even though permissions are correct. As soon as I remove the overridden `get_form()` method, the icons appear. I am using a form factory to render the ModelForm class to do some queryset filtering based on the current user, so I can't use `form = <ModelForm>` in the admin (the form needs to capture the `HttpRequest` object).

(Using Django 2.1 and Python 3.6)

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Reservation)
class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('room', 'check_in_date', 'check_out_date', 'guest', 'reserved_by', 'reserved_on')
    inlines = (RoomChangeInline,)


    fieldsets = ( 
    (None, {
        'fields': (
            ('room', 'guest'),
            ('check_in_date', 'check_out_date'),
            ('adults', 'children'),
            ('subtotal', 'taxes', 'deposit'),
            ('reserved_by', 'reserved_on')
        )
    }),)   

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return reservation_admin_form_factory(request)
```

**forms.py**

```
def reservation_admin_form_factory(request):
    class ReservationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta: 
            model = Reservation
            exclude = []
            widgets = {
                'check_in_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                'check_out_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
            }

        """ I have an __init__() method, but even if I remove it 
        the problem remains, so I am not showing it here. """

    return ReservationAdminForm
```

Comment: Does the same occur if you just say `form = ReservationAdminForm` in your `ReservationAdmin` and remove the `get_form()` method (and not use a form factory)?

Comment: When I do as you suggest, I see the buttons appear on the admin change form as expected.

Comment: Perhaps the original `get_form`  returns a form pointing to some HTML fields templates which include those buttons?

Comment: Thank you Raydel. Based on your suggestion I looked at the source for get_form(). The method calls modelform_factory(), which takes several parameters, the key parameter being `formfield_callback`. So my new code looks like this (sorry, couldn't get the formatting right in the comment so I used pastebin):

https://pastebin.com/raw/pf4jLhct

Comment: OK, that didn't work. Initially it appeared to be working, as the icons showed up, but in fact Django was completing ignoring my custom `ModelForm` object. The fix was to wrap the field's widget in a `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` call (see answer).

Answer (score 3):

To display the Add / Edit buttons on the Django admin change_form page when overriding the ModelAdmin's `get_form()` you need to wrap the field's widget in a `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` like so:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ManyToOneRel

def reservation_admin_form_factory(request, admin_site):
    class ReservationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Reservation
            exclude = []

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            rel = ManyToOneRel(Reservation.guest, Guest, 'id')
            self.fields['guest'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
                 self.fields['guest'].widget, rel, admin_site, 
                     can_change_related=True)
```

Note the above use of a form factory (`reservation_admin_form_factory`) to capture the `admin_site` object, which is needed by `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.

**admin.py***

```
@admin.register(Reservation)
class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('check_in_date', 'check_out_date')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.form = reservation_admin_form_factory(request, admin.site)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This almost works for me. Just that the popup doesn't open up and loads in the current tab/page instead. I am actually using a modified version of this as the intermediate page in a dajngo admin action with a custom template. I also tried adding `{{ form.media }}` in the template as I thought that the popup was called using JS. But that also didn't work for me.